# Как делать рассылку в Telegram [Python]?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram

Есть бот в телеграмме, так же есть база данных в которой находятся id пользователей бота
Бот написан на модуле PyTelegramBotApi

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обходить пользователей, которые заблокировали бота ( из-за них при рассылке бот падает)

Comment: сделать исключение try: except

Comment: найди человека который заблокировал бота, через дебаггер запусти бота и отправь сообщение конкретно ему, заскринь ответ полученный ботом, псмотрим что можно с этим делать